# drawing 3d contour plot from 3d vector

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, matlab-figure, contour

I want to draw a contour plot for 3D data.

I have a force in x,y,z directions I want to plot the contour3 for that

the dimensions of the Fx = 21x21X21 same for Fy and Fz

I am finding force = f*vector(x,y,z)
Then

```
Fx(x,y,z) = force(1)
Fy(x,y,z) = force(2)
Fz(x,y,z) = force(3)
```

I did the following but it is not working with me ?? why and how can I plot that

```
FS = sqrt(Fx.^2 + Fy.^2 + Fz.^2);

x = -10:1:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x); 
for i=1:length(FS)

   for j = 1:length(FS)
       for k=1:length(FS)
        contour3(X,Y,FS(i,j,k),10)
        hold on
      end
   end
end
```

This is the error I am getting 
Error using contour3 (line 129)
When Z is a vector, X and Y must also be vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `FS` is not the same shape as X and Y.

Lets illustrate with a simple example:

```
X=[1 1 1
   2 2 2
   3 3 3];
Y=[1 2 3
   1 2 3
   1 2 3];
Z=[ 2 4 5 1 2 5 5 1 2];
```

Your data is probably something like this. How does Matlab knows which Z entry corresponds to which X,Y position? He doesnt, and thats why he tells you `When Z is a vector, X and Y must also be vectors`.

You could solve this by doing `reshape(FS,size(X,1),size(X,2))` and will probably work in your case, but you need to be careful. In your example, `X` and `Y` don't seem programatically related to `FS` in any way. To have a meaningful contour plot, you need to make sure that `FS(ii,jj,k)`[ 1 ] corresponds to `X(ii,jj)`, else your contour plot would not make sense.

Generally you'd want to plot the result of `FS` against the variables your are using to compute it, such as `ii`, `jj` or `k`, however, I dont know how these look like so I will stop my explanation here.

[ 1 ]: [DO NOT CALL VARIABLES `i` and `j` IN MATLAB!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: My FS is 21X21X21 it is not a one array of data.. becasue it has been generated from 3 matrices and each one of them is 21X21X21...

Comment: So.... How do you expect to plot something like that? It makes no sense, you are talking baout a 5 dimensional plot (x,y, and the three dimensions of FS!). Humans have still not developed 5D graphics. @RSA. Try to substitute your Fx,Fy,Fz by simple data we can run, so we can suggest you ways of ploting.

Comment: @Crowley I have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: @Ander Biguri: If we apply normalisation we can assign x and y to coordinates in the figure and F_x to red colour, F_y to green colour and F_z to blue colour ing RGB colourspace. This way you obtain 2D representation of 5D space. But it is hard to imagine what this image shows... You can also go further to 6D (x,y,z,R,G,B) but it will be really creepy.

Comment: @Crowley That would give no information to the user, as we are incabale or separating RGB values from a seen color. Its not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solution is what you want.

Your problem is that `contour` and `contour3` are plots to represent scalar field in 2D objects. Note that ball is 2D object - every single point is defined by angles theta and phi - even it is an object in "space" not in "plane".

For representation of vector fields there is `quiver`, `quiver3`, `streamslice` and `streamline` functions.

If you want to use contour plot, you have to transform your data from vector field to scalar field. So your data in form **F** = f(x,y,z) must be transformed to form of H = f(x,y). In that case H is MxN matrix, x and y are Mx1 and Nx1 vectors, respectively. Then `contour3(x,y,H)` will work resulting in so-called 3D graph.

If you rely on vector field You have to specify 6 vectors/matrices of the same size of corresponding x, y, z coordinates and Fx, Fy, Fz vector values.
In that case quiver3(x,y,z,Fx,Fy,Fz) will work resulting in 6D graph. **Use it wisely!**

As I comment the Ander's answer, you can use colourspace to get more dimensions, so You can create 5D or, theoretically, 6D, because you have x, y, z coordinates for position and R, G, B coordinates for the values. I'd recommend using static (x,y,R,G,B) for 5D graph and animated (x,y,t,R,G,B) for 6D. **Use it wisely!**

In the example I show all approaches mentioned above. i chose gravity field and calculate the plane 0.25 units below the centre of gravity.

Assume a force field defined in polar coordinates as **F**=-**r**/r^3; F=1/r^2.
Here both *x* and *y*are in range of -1;1 and same size N.
**F** is the MxMx3 matrix where **F**(ii,jj) is force vector corresponding to *x*(ii) and *y*(jj).
Matrix *H*(ii,jj) is the norm of **F**(ii,jj) and *X*, *Y* and *Z* are matrices of coordinates.

Last command ensures that F values are in (-1;1) range. The `F./2+0.5` moves values of F so they fit into RGB range. The colour meaning will be:

- black for (-1,-1,-1),
- red for (1,-1,-1),
- grey for (0,0,0)

Un-comment the type of plot You want to see. For quiver use `resolution` of 0.1, for other cases use 0.01.

```
clear all,close all
% Definition of coordinates 
resolution=0.1;
x=-1:resolution:1;
y=x;
z=-.25;

%definition of matrices
F=zeros([max(size(x))*[1 1],3]);    % matrix of the force
X=zeros(max(size(x))*[1 1]);        % X coordinates for quiver3
Y=X;                                % Y coordinates for quiver3
Z=X+z;                              % Z coordinates for quiver3                              

% Force F in polar coordinates
% F=-1/r^2
% spherical -> cartesian transformation

for ii=1:max(size(x))
  for jj=1:max(size(y))
    % temporary variables for transformations
    xyz=sqrt(x(ii)^2+y(jj)^2+z^2);
    xy= sqrt(x(ii)^2+y(jj)^2);
    sinarc=sin(acos(z/xyz));

    %filling the quiver3 matrices
    X(ii,jj)=x(ii);
    Y(ii,jj)=y(jj);

    F(ii,jj,3)=-z/xyz^2;
    if xy~=0 % 0/0 error for x=y=0
       F(ii,jj,2)=-y(jj)/xyz/xy*sinarc;
       F(ii,jj,1)=-x(ii)/xyz/xy*sinarc;
    end
    H(ii,jj)=sqrt(F(ii,jj,1)^2+F(ii,jj,2)^2+F(ii,jj,3)^2);
  end
end

F=F./max(max(max(F)));
% quiver3(X,Y,Z,F(:,:,1),F(:,:,2),F(:,:,3));
% image(x,y,F./2+0.5),set(gca,'ydir','normal');
% surf(x,y,Z,F./2+.5,'linestyle','none')
% surf(x,y,H,'linestyle','none')
surfc(x,y,H,'linestyle','none')
% contour3(x,y,H,15)
```

Comment: If You change `F./2+0.5` by `abs(F)` the colourspace will change and You will get black for (0,0,0), red for both (1,0,0) and (-1,0,0) and grey for (0.5,0.5,0.5)

Comment: Great answer! This is what a good stackoverflow.com answer should look like