# 4 dimensional plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, plot, contour

I am trying to create a plot in Matlab with my 4 dimensional data. the data looks like [x,y,z,d] in which x,y and z are the coordinates of the object and "d" is the intensity. I tried to map the data and consider just [x,y,d] and do contour or surf but for that "d" should be a matrix. I also used plot3 but it does not look nice or like a contour. Any idea how to plot this in a nice way? 
Here is an example of the data:

```
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  1.054474998136970E-002
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  3.7500001E-02  1.348833743199940E-003
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  6.2500000E-02  0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  8.7499999E-02  0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.1125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.1375000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.1625000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.1875000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.2125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.2375000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.2625000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.2875000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.3125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.3375000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.3625000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.3875000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.4125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.4375000      7.452120128176466E-006
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.4625000      2.235636038452940E-005
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.4875000      4.471272076905880E-005
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.5125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.5375000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.5625000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.5875000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.6125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.6375000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.6625000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.6875000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.7125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.7375000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.7625000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.7875000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.8125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.8375000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.8625000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.8875000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.9125000      0.000000000000000E+000
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.9375000      7.824726134585290E-004
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.9625000      9.657947686116700E-003
  1.2500000E-02  1.2500000E-02  0.9875000      3.128400029808481E-002
  1.2500000E-02  3.7500001E-02  1.2500000E-02  1.028392577688352E-003
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the answer is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403655/drawing-3d-contour-plot-from-3d-vector/35510265#35510265

Comment: Can You describe your plot as a function `(z,d)=f(x,y)` or as `d=f(x,y,z)? In the first case you can use surf where `z` defines elevation and `d` describes colour. In the second case You have to chose a slice `z=f(x,y)` and use it to get `[z,d]=g(x,y)`. This I can advise you right now.

Comment: What dimension are your variables? Can you append the code you used for `plot` and the image? It might help understanding the data.

Comment: Your pasted data does not look like it actually defines a surface, for the same x and y value you have multiple z values. Does this describe a volume?

Comment: @Daniel That means, that the data represents, say, temperature in a volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we CAN transform your matrix in form `[x,y,z,T]` to form 3 vectors `X`, `Y`, `Z` and 3-D matrix `T` while `T(ii,jj,kk)` corresponds to `X(ii)`, `Y(jj)` and `Z(kk)`.

It is impossible to plot such field as it is, data visualized closest to the viewer will hide the rest, we can plot a subset of such field, let's call it *slice* although it doesn't meat it must be a plane.

In my code suppose the *slice* being defined as a function z=f(x,y).

In the first part I define `X`, `Y`, `Z` vectors and field `T` which intensity is equal to distance to `[0 0 0]` position.

Then I create *slice* and using encapsulated function `getTvalue` I calculate appropriate intesity.

> `getTvalue` interpolates `T(z)` dependence from the mesh and calculate the value for given Z.

Then I plot the *slice* using `surf` to show the geometry (first 3 parameters) the fourth represents the colour - which is, in our case, intensity.

```
function[]=plot4d()
clc,close all
% Define the mesh
N=21;
X=-1:1/(N-1):1;
Y=X;
Z=X;
M=size(X,2);

% Define intensity matrix
T=zeros(M,M,M);
for ii=1:M
  for jj=1:M
    for kk=1:M
      T(ii,jj,kk)=sqrt((X(ii))^2+(Y(jj))^2+(Z(kk))^2);
    end
  end
end

for ii=1:M
  for jj=1:M
    SliceZ(ii,jj)=X(ii)+(Y(jj)^2);    % This is the SLICE FUNCTION, here (z=x+y^2)
% Calculate T value for (ii,jj) position using Z mesh, T values and actual Z position)
    SliceT(ii,jj)=getTvalue(ii,jj,Z,T,SliceZ(ii,jj));
  end
end

% Plot surface in range of X and Y, elevation defined by SliceZ and colour defined by SliceT without lines
surf(X,Y,SliceZ,SliceT,'linestyle','none')
% Plot the cross locating [0 0 0] point
line('xdata',[-1 1],'ydata',[0 0],'zdata',[0 0])
line('ydata',[-1 1],'xdata',[0 0],'zdata',[0 0])
line('zdata',[-1 1],'ydata',[0 0],'xdata',[0 0])
axis equal
% plot4d ends here

%% Nested functions:

function[Tvalue]=getTvalue(xi,yj,Zvector,Tmatrix,Zvalue)
% Test if the actual slice position (Zvalue) is inside the mesh (Zvector)
if Zvalue>max(Zvector)||Zvalue<min(Zvector)
  % If not, return NaN and process to next iteration
  Tvalue=nan;
  return
end

M=max(size(Zvector));                      % get the size of Z mesh
Index=find(Zvalue<=Zvector,1)              % find interval inside which the Zvalue is

% Test if the Zvalue is on the edge of mesh (Zvector)
if Index==M
  % Zvalue is on the edge - return the edge value (it prevents the index overflow)
  Tvalue=Tmatrix(xi,yj,M);
else
% Zvalue is inside the mesh (Zvector)

% calculate the slope of T(x,y,z)=k*z(x,y)+q dependence.
k=(Tmatrix(xi,yj,Index)-Tmatrix(xi,yj,Index+1))/(Zvector(Index)-Zvector(Index+1));

% calculate transposition of the dependence   
q=Tmatrix(xi,yj,Index)-k*(Zvector(Index)); 

% calculate the actual value of T
Tvalue=k*Zvalue+q; 
end
% End of nested function
```

Comment: Answer is open to any edit of both code and/or explanation.

Comment: Actually, since `X` and `Y` are "functions" of indices `ii` and `jj` You can tune the function to have the *slice* as a ball, torus or any other shape You can define by vectors `X(ii)`, `Y(jj)` and matrix `Z(ii,jj)`. In other words, the slice must be defined by function `f(x,y,z)=0` and it is up to You how You define the `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `T`.